# Elasticsearch cardinality aggregation exception

Tags: elasticsearch

I am currently in the process of updating ES clusters from version 6 to 7 and, in version 7 a breaking change is introduced where [missing document values will throw an error](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/breaking-changes-7.0.html#_accessing_missing_document_values_will_throw_an_error).
My goal here is to alter this query and select all documents where those values exist and that should take care of my problem. How can I add a `must not contain` or `must contain` to this query to achieve my goal?

```
   {
       "query":{
          "bool":{
             "must":[
                {
                   "terms":{
                      "state":[
                         "pending",
                         "queued",
                         "deferred"
                      ]
                   }
                },
                {
                   "terms":{
                      "tenant_tag":[
                         "prod"
                      ]
                   }
                }
             ]
          }
       },
       "aggs":{
          "count":{
             "cardinality":{
                "script":"doc['user_id'].value + '_' + doc['campaign_id'].value"
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rewrite your query like this:

```
{
       "query":{
          "bool":{
             "filter":[
                {
                  "exists": { "field": "user_id" }
                },
                {
                  "exists": { "field": "campaign_id" }
                },
                {
                   "terms":{
                      "state":[
                         "pending",
                         "queued",
                         "deferred"
                      ]
                   }
                },
                {
                   "terms":{
                      "tenant_tag":[
                         "prod"
                      ]
                   }
                }
             ]
          }
       },
       "aggs":{
          "count":{
             "cardinality":{
                "script":"doc['user_id'].value + '_' + doc['campaign_id'].value"
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

Ideally, you should pre-compute the `userid_campaignid` field in your documents, so you don't have to use a scripted aggregation, which are terrible in terms of performance, especially since cardinality can already be terrible itself.